# Unable to pass user inputs into R shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app where on load it shows a default table. Have a user input which when I enter and click on run should update the table. And also when clicked on reset it should show the default table.As of now I am able to view the default table and nothing happens when I click on the run button.

```r
optimzation <- function(input, output, session, data,budget,run,reset) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data)

  observeEvent(run, {
    v$data <- data %>% mutate(carb = mpg * budget)
  })

  observeEvent(reset, {
    v$data <- data # your default data
  })  

  output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(v$data, filter = "top")
  })
}

optimzationUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dataTableOutput(ns("mod_table"))

}

shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      mainPanel(
        numericInput("budget_input", label = h5("Total Budget"), value = 9000000),
        actionButton("opt_run", "Run"),
        actionButton("opt_reset", "Reset"),
        tags$hr(),
        optimzationUI("optimize")
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      demodata<-mtcars
      callModule(optimzation,"optimize", demodata,budget=input$budget_input,run=input$opt_run,reset = input$opt_reset)

    }
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you need to be more careful when passing global user input to a shiny module. It seems it will "break" the reactivity. You can fix this my explicitly passing in a reactive object. Here's the updated module. Note the added `()` to get the current reactive value.

```
optimzation <- function(input, output, session, data, budget,run,reset) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data)

  observeEvent(run(), {
    v$data <- data %>% mutate(carb = mpg * budget())
  })

  observeEvent(reset(), {
    v$data <- data 
  })  

  output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(v$data, filter = "top")
  })
}

optimzationUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("mod_table"))      
}
```

and here's the changed app. note the explicit `reactive(input$....)`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(
      numericInput("budget_input", label = h5("Total Budget"), value = 9000000),
      actionButton("opt_run", "Run"),
      actionButton("opt_reset", "Reset"),
      tags$hr(),
      optimzationUI("optimize")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    demodata<-mtcars
    callModule(optimzation,"optimize", 
               data=demodata,
               budget=reactive(input$budget_input),
               run=reactive(input$opt_run),
               reset = reactive(input$opt_reset))        
  }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few problems with your code that make it not reproducible currently: `library(shiny)` and `library(dplyr)` need to be added, and the `dataTableOutput` needs to be prefixed with `DT::dataTableOutput`.

The next problem (which is the actual question you're asking about) is that the values you're passing to the module are currently being passed as just regular values at one snapshot in time. They should be passed as reactives instead. It's a bit counter intuitive because we think of inputs as reactive, but when you pass `input$reset` then you're passing the module the specific value at this point in time. Instead, you need to pass it `reactive(input$reset)`, and then in the module you access it with `reset()` instead of with `reset`. The same is true for the other reactives that are passed into the module.

Here's the complete code solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

optimzation <- function(input, output, session, data,budget,run,reset) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data)

  observeEvent(run(), {
    v$data <- data %>% mutate(carb = mpg * budget())
  })

  observeEvent(reset(), {
    v$data <- data # your default data
  })  

  output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(v$data, filter = "top")
  })
}

optimzationUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("mod_table"))

}

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(
      numericInput("budget_input", label = h5("Total Budget"), value = 9000000),
      actionButton("opt_run", "Run"),
      actionButton("opt_reset", "Reset"),
      tags$hr(),
      optimzationUI("optimize")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    demodata<-mtcars
    callModule(optimzation,"optimize", demodata,
               budget = reactive(input$budget_input),
               run = reactive(input$opt_run),
               reset = reactive(input$opt_reset))

  }
)
```